# how to clear failing DAGs using the CLI in airflow

Tags: airflow

I have some failing DAGs, let's say from 1st-Feb to 20th-Feb. From that date upword, all of them succeeded.

I tried to use the [cli](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#clear) (instead of doing it twenty times with the Web UI):

`airflow clear -f -t * my_dags.my_dag_id`

But I have a weird error:

```
airflow: error: unrecognized arguments: airflow-webserver.pid airflow.cfg airflow_variables.json my_dags.my_dag_id
```

**EDIT 1:**

Like @tobi6 explained it, the `*` was indeed causing troubles.
Knowing that, I tried this command instead:

```
airflow clear -u -d -f -t ".*" my_dags.my_dag_id
```

but it's only returning failed task instances (`-f` flag). `-d` and `-u` flags don't seem to work because taskinstances downstream and upstream the failed ones are ignored (not returned).

**EDIT 2:**

like @tobi6 suggested, using `-s` and `-e` permits to select all DAG runs within a date range. Here is the command:

```
airflow clear  -s "2018-04-01 00:00:00" -e "2018-04-01 00:00:00"  my_dags.my_dag_id.
```

However, adding `-f` flag to the command above only returns failed task instances. is it possible to select all failed task instances of all failed DAG runs within a date range ?

Comment: Have you tried only using one of `-u -d`? Also, did you try with providing a start and end date with the `-s` or `-e` parameters?

Comment: When I only use `-u -d` all the DAG runs are returned including thoses that have suceeded, I don't want them to be cleaned. I'm only interested in those that have failed.
I don't want to alter the execution date because the DAG processing is related to it.

Comment: I meant using `-u -f ...` or `-d -f ...` separately. You don't alter the execution date but select those DAGs which had an execution date within the period. That might help.

Comment: the documentation is misleading. it is saying:
`-s` Override start_date YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: using `-u -f ..` or  `-d -f ...` is selecting same set of task instances. I think it's because `-f` is more restrective. From the documentation:
`-f ` Only failed jobs

Answer (score 5):

If you are using an asterik `*` in the Linux bash, it will automatically expand the content of the directory.

Meaning it will replace the asterik with all files in the current working directory and *then* execute your command.

This will help to avoid the automatic expansion:

```
"airflow clear -f -t * my_dags.my_dag_id"
```

Comment: This quoting will treat the entire command as a single string. You probably want `airflow clear -f -t '*' my_dags.my_dag_id`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've found so far is by executing sql(MySQL in my case):

```
update task_instance t left join dag_run d on d.dag_id = t.dag_id and d.execution_date = t.execution_date
set t.state=null,
    d.state='running'
where t.dag_id = '<your_dag_id'
  and t.execution_date > '2020-08-07 23:00:00'
  and d.state='failed';
```

It will clear all tasks states on failed dag_runs, as button 'clear' pressed for entire dag run in web UI.

Answer (score -1):

In airflow 2.2.4 the `airflow clear` command was deprecated.

You could now run:

`airflow tasks clear  -s <your_start_date> -e <end_date> <dag_id>`